# VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest detecting of the face

Tags: swift, swift4, apple-vision

I am using [Vision](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) framework to process images. Function that i am using for that is running well and do not return any error in completion handler but result is empty.

This is my function :

```
 func recognizeImage() {
        let request = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest { (res: VNRequest, error: Error?) in
            print("Reuslt : \(res.accessibilityActivationPoint)")
        }

        if let cgContet = image.image.cgImage  {
            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgContet)
            try? handler.perform([request])
        }
    }
```

Result of the function is :

```
Reuslt : (0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: what exactly is being asked here?

Comment: @rambossa why function that is used return empty result without any error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not quite enough info here to be sure, but probably...

Face recognition requires that the image orientation be known. (Because accurately figuring out which blobs of pixels are and aren't faces is a heck of a lot easier when you're looking for right-side-up faces only.)

`CGImage` doesn't know it's own orientation, so you have to get that info separately and pass it to one of the `VNImageRequestHandler` initializers [that takes an orientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagerequesthandler/2869629-init).

Those initializers take an EXIF orientation value (aka [`CGImagePropertyOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimagepropertyorientation)). If you're starting from a `UIImage`, that enum's underlying numeric values don't match those of `UIImageOrientation`, so you'll need to convert them. There's a handy method for doing that in the [sample code attached to the Vision session from WWDC17](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc17/506).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to detect faces and draw a rectangle on each, try this:

```
let request=VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest{request, error in
    var final_image=UIImage(named: image_to_process)

    if let results=request.results as? [VNFaceObservation]{
        print(results.count, "faces found")
        for face_obs in results{
          //draw original image
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(final_image.size, false, 1.0)
          final_image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: final_image.size.width, height: final_image.size.height))

          //get face rect
          var rect=face_obs.boundingBox
          let tf=CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -final_image.size.height)
          let ts=CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: final_image.size.width, y: final_image.size.height)
          let converted_rect=rect.applying(ts).applying(tf)    

          //draw face rect on image
          let c=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
          c.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
          c.setLineWidth(0.01*final_image.size.width)
          c.stroke(converted_rect)

          //get result image
          let result=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

          final_image=result!
        }
    }

    //display final image
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.image_view.image=final_image
    }
}


guard let ciimage=CIImage(image:image_to_process) else{
  fatalError("couldn't convert uiimage to ciimage")
}

let handler=VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciimage)
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async{
    do{
        try handler.perform([request])
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that has been helpful to me in all cases, including when my *UIImageView* is embedded in a *UIScrollView* or when orientation changes.  Other responses on StackOverflow have been helpful in some scenarios, especially when dealing with pixel buffers and live camera feeds, but this was *very* helpful for UIImages in almost all cases.

Comment: Glad it could help @ZbadhabitZ! :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem made me be crazy too. It turns out the original problem is orientation of the image which both cgiImage or ciiImage cannot handle correctly. Some code I have copied from somewhere converted wrongly orientation from image to cgi one by simple casting (they are not same order).

I have created an orientation converter and the below code works for me:

```
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image.cgImage!, orientation: self.convertImageOrientation(orientation: image.imageOrientation))

...

func convertImageOrientation(orientation: UIImageOrientation) -> CGImagePropertyOrientation  {
    let cgiOrientations : [ CGImagePropertyOrientation ] = [
        .up, .down, .left, .right, .upMirrored, .downMirrored, .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored
    ]

    return cgiOrientations[orientation.rawValue]
}
```